Is energy eternal?
I have a crystal that is made of k9 glass. will the energy that is apart of this crystal always exist since energy cannot be destroyed. will it exist after the heat death in some form? Or will everything about it cease to exist its energy to?

What does the word "eternal" mean in physics? In particular, how would you test it?

This might help - How is energy "stored in an electric field"?

After heat death, your crystal will not be a crystal any more, but the energy will remain the same. Depending on theories, after heat death your crystal may become just a bunch of photons.

If we ignore gravity (because energy is not conserved in general relativity), then the answer is yes: you could follow the energy associated with the crystal into the future as far as you want, and it will still be around in some form. In the case of a "heat death," the energy would be in the form of random motion of particles.
